# Styling cell borders with PhpSpreadsheet PHP

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I use PhpSpreadsheet to read o write in Excel files. I want to add to my excel a border style so I used this code:

```
<?php
    $fxls ='myfile.xlsx';
    $spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load($fxls);
    $xls_data = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true, true, true);
    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

    $styleArray = array(
        'borders' => array(
            'outline' => array(
                'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THICK,
                'color' => array('argb' => 'FFFF0000'),
            ),
        ),
    );

    $sheet ->getStyle('B2:G8')->applyFromArray($styleArray);

    /* Generate the Excel File */
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myNEWFile.xlsx"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
    header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
    header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate');
    header ('Pragma: public');
    $writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $writer->save('php://output');
    exit;
```

I get no error but the excel file is created without border. What I miss !??

Comment: Your script works for me. All I changed is to include the autoloader and adjust the excel filename.

Answer (score 39):

### tl;dr

Beyond the [style array way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47035139/1494454) you can also do it in the method chaining way:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Color;

$spreadsheet
    ->getActiveSheet()
    ->getStyle('B2')
    ->getBorders()
    ->getOutline()
    ->setBorderStyle(Border::BORDER_THICK)
    ->setColor(new Color('FFFF0000'));
```

Blatantly copied from the [official docs on cell formatting](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#formatting-cells).

### Available border patterns

The [docs on cell formatting](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#formatting-cells) contains a list of available patterns and their keys used in the style array form. For the method chaining form just slap a `get` before the capitalized version of the key. These methods are all available under `->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B2')->getBorders()` just like in the example.

- On a single cell:

  - left: `->getLeft()`
  - right: `->getRight()`
  - top: `->getTop()`
  - bottom: `->getBottom()`
  - diagonal: `->getDiagonal()`
- On an area:

  - allBorders: `->getAllBorders()`
  - outline: `->getOutline()`
  - inside: `->getInside()`
  - vertical: `->getVertical()`
  - horizontal: `->getHorizontal()`

The patterns visualized (also from the [docs](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#formatting-cells)):

[image]

### Available border styles

```
Border::BORDER_DASHDOT
Border::BORDER_DASHDOTDOT
Border::BORDER_DASHED
Border::BORDER_DOTTED
Border::BORDER_DOUBLE
Border::BORDER_HAIR
Border::BORDER_MEDIUM
Border::BORDER_MEDIUMDASHDOT
Border::BORDER_MEDIUMDASHDOTDOT
Border::BORDER_MEDIUMDASHED
Border::BORDER_NONE
Border::BORDER_SLANTDASHDOT
Border::BORDER_THICK
Border::BORDER_THIN
```

Answer (score 9):

You need reassign value to sheet:

```
$styleArray = array(
    'borders' => array(
        'outline' => array(
            'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THICK,
            'color' => array('argb' => 'FFFF0000'),
        ),
    ),
);

$sheet = $sheet ->getStyle('B2:G8')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
$styleArray = array(
    'borders' => array(
        'outline' => array(
            'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THICK,
            'color' => array('argb' => 'FFFF0000'),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Replace by :

```
$styleArray = array(
    'borders' => array(
        'outline' => array(
            'style' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THICK,
            'color' => array('argb' => 'FFFF0000'),
        ),
    ),
);
```

[See](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/1.0.0-beta/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Style.php) in line 169-203.

`borderStyle` has been add after the 1.0.0-beta2 release in 2017-11-26.

Before, borders configuration was still with `style`

Comment: The two parts are identical.

Comment: it's not : 'borderStyle' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THICK, to 'style' => \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THICK,

Comment: Sorry. I must have been blind. But it's wrong though. `style` was for PHPExcel. They changed it to `borderStyle` in PhpSpreedsheet. https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/#styles - OPs code works for me.

Comment: Yes indeed, but it's the cofiguration from 1.0.0 release updated on 2017-12-25, this post has been posted on Oct.2017 when phpspreadsheet was on 1.0.0-beta -> https://packagist.org/packages/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet#1.0.0-beta, you can see on github the configuration was still "style" and not "borderStyle" -> https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/1.0.0-beta/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Style.php in line 169-203

Comment: Please add that info to your answer. I can't change my vote without edit.

Comment: As of v1.2, borderStyle works. Of note, the fill property type is now fillType, and allborders is now allBorders