# phpspreadsheet - lines without markers in chart

Tags: php, charts, styles, linechart, phpspreadsheet

I am using phpspreadsheet to generate line charts. Almost everything is fine, but I don't get how to change plot style.

Here is what I have:

```
function createChart($sheet, $sheetname, $data) {

    $count = $data["custom"]["count"];

    $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn(1)->setAutoSize(true);
    $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, 1, $data["custom"]["type"]);


    for($j=0; $j < $count; $j++)
        $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(1, $j + 2, $data["custom"]["dates"][$j]);

    for($i=0; $i< count($data["series"]); $i++) {

        $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i+2, 1, $data["series"][$i]["name"]);
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($i+2)->setAutoSize(true);

        for($j=0; $j < $count; $j++)
        {

            $value = $data["series"][$i]["data"][$j] ? $data["series"][$i]["data"][$j] : 0;
            $sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($i+2, $j + 2, $value);
        }
    }

    $dsl=array();

    for($i=0; $i< count($data["series"]); $i++) {
        $series = new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_STRING, $sheetname . '!' .
         $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i+2, 1)->getCoordinate(), NULL, 1, [], NULL, NULL);
        array_push($dsl, $series);
    }

    $xal=array(
        new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, $sheetname . '!'.
            $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, 2)->getCoordinate() . ':' .
            $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $count + 2)->getCoordinate()  , NULL, $count)
    );

    $dsv = array();

    for($i=0; $i< count($data["series"]); $i++) {
        $series = new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, $sheetname . '!'.
            $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i+2, 2)->getCoordinate() . ':' .
            $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i+2, $count + 2)->getCoordinate()  , NULL, $count);
        array_push($dsv, $series);
    }

    $type = "";

    switch($data["series"][0]["type"]) {

        case CHART_TYPE_BARCHART:
            $type = DataSeries::TYPE_BARCHART;
        break;
        case CHART_TYPE_LINECHART:
            $type = DataSeries::TYPE_LINECHART;
        break;
        default:
          $type = DataSeries::TYPE_LINECHART;  
    }

    $ds = new DataSeries(
        $type,
        DataSeries::GROUPING_STANDARD,
        range(0, count($dsv)-1),
        $dsl,
        $xal,
        $dsv,
        null,
        true,
        DataSeries::STYLE_MARKER
    );

    $pa = new PlotArea(NULL, array($ds));


    $legend = new Legend(Legend::POSITION_BOTTOM, NULL, false);

    $title = new Title($data["title"]["text"]);


    $chart = new Chart(
        'chart1',
        $title,
        $legend,
        $pa,
        0,
        0,
        NULL,
        NULL
    );

    $chart->setTopLeftPosition( $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(count($data["series"]) + 3, 1)->getCoordinate());
    $chart->setBottomRightPosition($sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(count($data["series"]) + 17, 40)->getCoordinate());

    $sheet->addChart($chart);

}
```

Specifically, I would like to draw lines without markers.

I tried passing all possible values the `$plotStyle` parameter of the `Dataseries` constructor, but this didn't have any effect.

I know from the [API docs](https://phpoffice.github.io/PhpSpreadsheet/master/PhpOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/Chart/Properties.html) that there is a `Properties` class which defines many constants influencing a chart's style, but I don't get how to use it, as it doesn't seem to be referenced by other classes.

I also know from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46959282/styling-cell-borders-with-phpspreadsheet-php) that one can set style properties of the document being created, is this the right way? How to navigate to the chart's properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it myself. All I needed to do was passing the string `"none"` to the parameter `$marker` of the `DataSeriesValues` constructor:

```
DataSeriesValues::__construct(
    string $dataType = self::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER,  
    string $dataSource = null
    , null|mixed $formatCode = null,
    int $pointCount = 0,
    mixed $dataValues = [],
    null|mixed $marker = null,
    null|string $fillColor = null
)
```

So the relevant part of my code becomes:

```
for($i=0; $i< count($data["series"]); $i++) {
    $series = new DataSeriesValues(DataSeriesValues::DATASERIES_TYPE_NUMBER, $sheetname . '!'.
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i+2, 2)->getCoordinate() . ':' .
        $sheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($i+2, $count + 2)->getCoordinate()  , NULL, $count, [], "none");
    array_push($dsv, $series);
}
```